# Imputting the value in R and Stata

Tags: r, stata

I have a dataset, which I call `sam.data`:

```
dput(sam.data)
structure(list(idn = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 66L, 62L, 7L, 
81L, 68L, 72L), n1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L), x = c(9.95228, 11.4186, 10.3735, 10.5453, 10.7364, 9.85219, 
9.73307, 9.86304, 9.74097, 9.57359, 9.70899, 9.75185)), .Names = c("idn", 
"n1", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")

sam.data

    idn n1     x
1    1  1  9.95228
2    2  2 11.41860
3    3  3 10.37350
4    4  4 10.54530
5    5  5 10.73640
6    6  6  9.85219
7   66  6  9.73307
8   62  6  9.86304
9    7  7  9.74097
10  81  7  9.57359
11  68  7  9.70899
12  72  7  9.75185
```

For `idn` not equal to `n1`, I want to create a new variable `y`, which takes a value of `x` corresponding to `n1`, otherwise I would like it to be assigned as missing.

The expected output should look as follows:

```
   idn n1        x        y
1    1  1  9.95228  
2    2  2 11.41860 
3    3  3 10.37350 
4    4  4 10.54530 
5    5  5 10.73640 
6    6  6  9.85219 
7   66  6  9.73307  9.85219
8   62  6  9.86304  9.85219
9    7  7  9.74097 
10  81  7  9.57359  9.74097
11  68  7  9.70899  9.74097
12  72  7  9.75185  9.74097
```

I was able to generate a close solution in R:

```
library(plyr)
sam.data2<-ddply(sam.data,.(n1),transform, y=x[which.min(idn)])
sam.data2
 sam.data2
   idn n1        x        y
1    1  1  9.95228  9.95228
2    2  2 11.41860 11.41860
3    3  3 10.37350 10.37350
4    4  4 10.54530 10.54530
5    5  5 10.73640 10.73640
6    6  6  9.85219  9.85219
7   66  6  9.73307  9.85219
8   62  6  9.86304  9.85219
9    7  7  9.74097  9.74097
10  81  7  9.57359  9.74097
11  68  7  9.70899  9.74097
12  72  7  9.75185  9.74097
```

However, I would prefer to have a more elegant solution.

I am also looking for a solution in Stata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option using `by`  from the base package.

```
dat$y <- unlist(by(dat,dat$n1,  FUN=    
      function(x){
        res <- ifelse(x$idn==x$n1,
               NA,
               x$x[which.min(x$idn)])
        }))
```

Note here the result is slightly different of the desired output , since I use NA ( numeric) and not `` which is string.

```
  idn n1        x       y
1    1  1  9.95228      NA
2    2  2 11.41860      NA
3    3  3 10.37350      NA
4    4  4 10.54530      NA
5    5  5 10.73640      NA
6    6  6  9.85219      NA
7   66  6  9.73307 9.85219
8   62  6  9.86304 9.85219
9    7  7  9.74097      NA
10  81  7  9.57359 9.74097
11  68  7  9.70899 9.74097
12  72  7  9.75185 9.74097
```

Comment: Thanks agstudy for the `R` solution. I prefer using NA because I want the column to be numeric.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you want this for but simply using your output you can make it look like your desired out put by seeing where x equals y and replacing it with `""`:

```
sam.data2$y[sam.data2$x == sam.data2$y] <- ""
sam.data2

## > sam.data2
##    idn n1        x       y
## 1    1  1  9.95228        
## 2    2  2 11.41860        
## 3    3  3 10.37350        
## 4    4  4 10.54530        
## 5    5  5 10.73640        
## 6    6  6  9.85219        
## 7   66  6  9.73307 9.85219
## 8   62  6  9.86304 9.85219
## 9    7  7  9.74097        
## 10  81  7  9.57359 9.74097
## 11  68  7  9.70899 9.74097
## 12  72  7  9.75185 9.74097
```

There are few approaches to this and depending on what you want to use this for would depend on which approach to take.  If it's purely for aesthetics then the above is pretty easy but now the column is character and not numeric.

Comment: Thank you Tyler. I didn't knew that the column will be non-numeric for that.

Answer (score 1):

Stata Solution:

```
capture net install xfill, from(http://www.sealedenvelope.com/)
bys n1: gen y2=x/(idn==n1) 
xfill y2, i(n1) 
replace y2=. if n1==idn
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitriy for the `stata` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Stata code could just be

```
sort n1, stable
by n1: gen y2 = x[1] if idn != n1
```

(This is a revised suggestion.)

Comment: Thanks Nick for the `stata` solution.

Comment: @ Nick : I think you need to replace `id` with `n1` in your solution. However, even that didn't give me the solution as I wanted.

Comment: Sorry about misreading your variable names. The revised code above reproduces your example.

Answer (score 0):

@Nick's Stata solution can actually be done in one line using `bysort`:

```
clear

input idn n1 x y
1  1  9.95228  9.95228
2  2 11.41860 11.41860
3  3 10.37350 10.37350
4  4 10.54530 10.54530
5  5 10.73640 10.73640
6  6  9.85219  9.85219
66  6  9.73307  9.85219
62  6  9.86304  9.85219
7  7  9.74097  9.74097
81  7  9.57359  9.74097
68  7  9.70899  9.74097
72  7  9.75185  9.74097
end

bysort n1: gen y2 = x[1] if idn != n1

list

     +----------------------------------------+
     | idn   n1         x         y        y2 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |   1    1   9.95228   9.95228         . |
  2. |   2    2   11.4186   11.4186         . |
  3. |   3    3   10.3735   10.3735         . |
  4. |   4    4   10.5453   10.5453         . |
  5. |   5    5   10.7364   10.7364         . |
     |----------------------------------------|
  6. |   6    6   9.85219   9.85219         . |
  7. |  66    6   9.73307   9.85219   9.85219 |
  8. |  62    6   9.86304   9.85219   9.85219 |
  9. |   7    7   9.74097   9.74097         . |
 10. |  81    7   9.57359   9.74097   9.74097 |
     |----------------------------------------|
 11. |  68    7   9.70899   9.74097   9.74097 |
 12. |  72    7   9.75185   9.74097   9.74097 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```